# Здравствуйте. Не получается ограничить вывод количества блоков

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, поиск

Не получается ограничить вывод количества блоков в поиске, то есть происходит вывод товаров через foreach(php), и там около 1000 товаров, но нужно, чтобы выводилось 6-10 товаров. LIMIT в запросе ставил, но это не то, нужно чтобы поиск работал по всем товарам. Если что, поиск осуществляется через jcfilter.js

Пример кода

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product_digiseller";
    $all = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    foreach ($all as $game) { 
?>
        <li id="<?= $game['activation'];  ?> item" class="main__list-item" style="width: 100%; display: block;">
          <a>
            <div class="popular-main__name">
              <span class="popular-item__name-span"><?= $game['name']; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="popular-main__price">
              <span class="popular-item__price-span"><?= $game['price']; ?> ₽</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
<?  }  ?>
```

[image: скриншот поиска]

Comment: вам по картинке погадать, или код какой-то приложите и ссылки на документацию к библиотеке? поиск по всем товарам и лимит друг друга не исключают

Answer (score 0):

## sql

`SELECT * FROM product_digiseller DESC LIMIT 10`

### ограничение строк

- https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/4.4.php

  - LIMIT - лимит
    `SELECT * FROM product_digiseller LIMIT 10`
    `SELECT * FROM product_digiseller LIMIT 5, 10`

### сортировка по возрастанию/убыванию

- https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/4.3.php

  - ASC - по возрастанию (по умолчанию)
    `SELECT * FROM product_digiseller ASC`
  - DESC - с конца
    `SELECT * FROM product_digiseller DESC`